# The MicroBlade Server can not use two ports

Tags: networking, switch, supermicro

Using SuperMicro network module, which related to Intel SDN product,
[the command PDF](https://www.supermicro.org.cn/manuals/other/Command_Line_Reference_SMCI_Rev_1.2.pdf) . and the [Web GUI manual](https://www.supermicro.org.cn/manuals/microblade/WebUI_Guide_MicroBlade.pdf).

the product is: [MicroBlade](https://www.supermicro.org.cn/newsroom/news/DataCenter_MicroBlade.cfm).

Now my problem is:

I started 3 nodes of the MicroBlade. you see there lighted 3 ports. they are `1`, `3`, `5`, and the `1`, `3`, `5` ports works fine.

[image]

but I have a problem, I want the three server use the other network adapter.

the bellow is one of my started server.

[image]

seems the other network adapter is not connected to the Switch module. 
you also can see the first image, the `2`, `4`, `6` port are Down status.

there I guess every server use two ports of the switch module. such as server1 use `1` and `2` ports.

so, how can I let server1 use the `2` port?

I tried `no shutdown` the `xe2`, but no use.

[image]

Comment: Check whether the network port corresponding to Onboard LAN2 on server1 is connected to port 2 on the switch.

Comment: this is a switch module, not there is no lines.

Comment: If switch module is a physical one or virtual one?
If it is a physical one, we need to connect it with physical network cable.